# face detection in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, emgucv, face-recognition

I'm trying to write a simple program that will detect a face off a webcam and then trigger an event(optionally take a snapshot of the face)

I don't need anything fancy like to compare it to other faces I just need to send out an email that someone is at the door (hopefully with attached photo)

the problem is im very confused about how and what to use

I see there is a very powerful "opencv" that has a few wrapper classes namely opencv.net and emgu.cv

I've seen a few examples here and there but i have yet to find a working set of source code that works with flex 4

Can anyone recommend what the best course of action for a amateur programmer like me.

thanks

Comment: The best course of action is that you grit your teeth and start programming. That is the only way a self-confessed _amateur_ will master the language.

Comment: unfortunately not an amateur task user.  Like pranav said, dig in.  I am working on this as well and I'm 6,400 lines of code deep and still have more to go.  It's cool as crap... but always gotta consider things like "what if I look kinda like someone else from utah"... your face rec app will give you 50 possible matches... then lots to do from there.  Not a "amateur" task.  However, if you want to dig deep, reply here and I will post some links to get you digging.

Answer (score 0):

There is an OpenCV AS3 Port for face detection called MariLena, here is a nice article and optimization by Quasimodo with downloadable example: http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000687.php
Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://code.google.com/p/face-recognition-library-as3/ it's easy to use it can crop images of detected faces and it can recognize person base on face image. You can find tutorial and examples on project page.